# Styling a <script> generated content

Tags: css, styling

I am trying to style the class `widgetcontainer` which is inserted into the page by adding this script to the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://widget.ratings.food.gov.uk/fhrswidget.jss?FHRSID=12345&Culture=en-GB"?</script>
```

EDIT: This is the code that is generated onto the page below the script..

```
<div id="CoreJsBaseDiv" class="widgetwrapper">
  <div class="widget1" classname="widget1">
     <div class="widget2" classname="widget2">
       <div class="widget3" classname="widget3">
          <div id="eventList" class="widgetcontainer" classname="widgetcontainer"><div>
          <a title="The Family Pizza Company" href="http://ratings.food.gov.uk/business/624197" class="listhyperlink" classname="listhyperlink">
            <div>The Family Pizza Company</div>
          </a>
          <div>CO14 8AW</div>
          <div>
             <img src="http://ratings.food.gov.uk/images/scores/small/fhrs_5_en-gb.JPG">
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    <br></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

when I add styling to my CSS to `.widgetcontainer` it doesn't work, I am wondering if there is a way to style this element doing some clever coding?

Comment: Posting just the script tag line is not enough for someone to help you. Post the rendered HTML and the CSS you are attempting.

Comment: [I can't reproduce the problem](http://jsbin.com/yacusu/1/edit?html,css,output).

Comment: sorry, I have edited the post

Comment: add style using parent class like this `.widgetwrapper .widgetcontainer{}`

Comment: Use 'inspect element' in Google Chrome, it will show you what styles are being applied. If you are trying to style something that already has styling applied then you'll need to be sure you're targeting it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely something must be overriding your styles. (Note your script tag lacks `>` closing and it's `src` has a typo, it's ending with a `?` after quotes):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://widget.ratings.food.gov.uk/fhrswidget.jss?FHRSID=12345&Culture=en-GB"?</script>
```

Should be something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://widget.ratings.food.gov.uk/fhrswidget.jss?FHRSID=12345&Culture=en-GB"></script>
```

For styles overriding, you can try several approaches:

- Try impacting by ID `#eventList {property: value;}`
- Try a more specific selector such as `div.widgetwrapper div.widgetcontainer {property: value;}` or even more specific if needed e.g. `div.widgetwrapper div.widget1 div.widget2 div.widget3 div.widgetcontainer {property: value;}`
- Only as last alternative you can use `!important`: `.widgetcontainer {property: value !important;}`